# ImageButton фон не корректно отображает

Tags: android

У меня все иконки в папке mipmap-hdpi, но тут я захотел задать фон нажатой кнопки, как пишут нужно создать селектор,и по стандарту он вытягивает кнопку из папки drawable что я и сделал.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wok_ovosh_7na8" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wok_ovosh_7na8_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wok_ovosh_7na8_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wok_ovosh_7na8" />
</selector>
```

и сослался в xml

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_wok"
        **android:src="@mipmap/ic_wok_ovosh_7na8"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background_selector"**
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>`
```

Но проблема в том, что ImageButton из папки drawable накладывается поверх другого из mipmap-hdp (что и логично так как я указал в xml коде) и оно больше, хотя и фон работает, но преобразует как то по своих размерах, не как из mipmap-hdpi, и из-за этого весь лейаут кривит. 
В этом собственно и вопрос, возможно ли обойтись без папки drawable в этом деле?Или нужно переделывать все иконки и помещать туда чтобы был фон?

Вот скрины, какие иконки до добавления селектора [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот тут с использованием селектора и как все падает, я специально заскринил нажатую кнопку, что бы Вы видели что все работает, но именно с лейаутом проблемы начинаются, так как relative layout помещен в scroll view
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задайте в качестве бэкграунда и реакции на нажатие однородный фон разного цвета\оттенка или уберите атрибут `android:src`, если надо чтобы именно иконка была другой при нажатии или назначте ваш селектор для `android:src`, а не для бэкграунда, бэкграунд не указывайте - в зависимости от того, какой результат вам надо получить

Comment: @pavlofff, Я переназначил селектор на android:src, но размер imagebutton все-равно не такой какой мне нужен, и из-за этого сыпиться лейаут, там много элементов.

Задать бекграунд imagebutton цветом я не могу, так как при создании проекта Android Studio сама создает стандартный серый фон для imagebutton, и сколько я не копался взял просто его отключил android:background="@null", так что единственный способ, наверное, менять фон именно сменой картинки, но в свою очередь идет это не очень понятное масштабирование Что порекомендуете?)

Comment: Опишите свою задачу подробнее (отредактировав вопрос). Какой размер вам нужен, какой получается, что хотите получить, желательно скриншоты. Android Studio это IDE - просто программа для удобного написания кода и сборки проекта, она сама не создает никакие фоны, это определено в фреймворке Android.

Comment: @pavlofff Добавил скрины на главную, чтобы Вы понимали о чем я, я в кодинге новичек, так чтоизвиняйте за элементарщину)

Comment: А у вас по геометрическому размеру в пикселях одинаковые изображения нормальной картинки и нажатой? Уберите из атрибутов `ImageView` параметр `android:src="@mipmap/ic_wok_ovosh_7na8"`, что получится?

Comment: @pavlofff Получится ровно то, что на 2й картинке там я так и сделал, убрал android:src="@mipmap/ic_wok_ovosh_7na8" , селектор их масштабирует почему то. Что нажатая, что не нажатая кнопка имеют одно разрешение - 232*198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю следующее решение (здесь на шесть ячеек, но вы можете добавить любое нужное количество):

Отказаться от `RelativeLayout`так как это довольно ресурсоемкий контейнер, который здесь не нужен, в пользу наиболее подходящего для данной разметки `TableLayout` с автовыравниванием столбцов (`android:stretchColumns="*"`). Вместо `ImageButton` использовать `ImageView`, так он не имеет дефолтного бэкграунда. Здесь для всех `ImageView` в качестве изображения задан один ресурс-селектор *selectable_image1.xml*, вы естественно для каждой ячейки сделаете свой, с разными картинками:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/selectable_image1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/selectable_image1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/selectable_image1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/selectable_image1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/selectable_image1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/selectable_image1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

параметр `android:paddingTop="30dp"` в элементах `tableRow` задает расстояние между рядами.

Сами изображения. В данном случае, думаю, будет уместно использовать изображение одного размера под все плотности экрана (*hdpi*, *xhdpi* и тд), собственным размером в пикселях достаточным для качественного отображения на экранах *xhdpi*, на остальных экранах оно будет отмасштабировано через параметр `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` для `ImageView`. Ставим для `ImageView` параметр  `android:clickable="true"`, чтобы он реагировал на нажатия.

Чтобы сделать реакцию на нажатие, я предлагаю не делать еще один комплект изображений, а просто добавить рамку к уже существующим изображениям, это позволит сократить размер приложения.

Делаем ресурс для нажатого состояния. На изображение накладываем рамку (прямоугольник) толщиной *5dp* с скруглениями в *10dp* (вы можете подобрать свои значения). Фоном заливки всего прямоугольника указываем прозрачный - *#0000*, чтобы изображение было видно и отображалась только рамка. Назовем его *press_image1.xml*. Помещаем в папку *res/drawable/*:

**press_image1.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@mipmap/image1" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid
                android:color="#0000"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dip"
                android:color="#3dbc24" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Где *image1* - изображение в ячейке.

Делаем селектор, чтобы реагировал на нажатия, назовем его *selectable_image1.xml*, помещаем в папку */res/drawable/*/ Этот селектор будет в качестве источника изображения в `ImageView`, который мы указываем через параметр `android:src`:

**selectable_image1.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/press_image1" />
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/image1" />
</selector>
```

Ну вот и все. Вам нужно будет проделать аналогичную работу для каждой картинки.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Вы просто очень помогли, целую лекцию прям расписали!