# Android - как правильно добавлять картинку на button

Tags: java, android

Имеется **png** картинка и цель - добавить её на **button**. Проблема в том, что если добавляю через `@android:background` кнопки, то картинка становится с лесенками (как будто антиалиазинг выключен), либо становится мутной.
Если использую разметку ниже, то вообще картинка не показывается, остаются только границы на button.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:drawable="@drawable/lmb_leaved" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" />
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="30dp" />
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#000000" android:startColor="#000000" />

                <stroke android:width="4px" android:color="#FF00BB2B" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:drawable="@drawable/lmb_pressed" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" />
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="30dp" />
                <gradient android:endColor="#000000" android:startColor="#000000" />

                <stroke android:width="20px" android:color="#FF00BB2B" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Имеются предоположения, что неправильно добавляю png в проект. Добавляю через
**res->new->image asset**

**Исправил, теперь всё работает**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/lkmveryhigh" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="30dp" />
                <solid
                    android:color="#0000"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="5dip"
                    android:color="#FF00BB2B" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        </layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/lkmveryhigh" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="30dp" />
                <solid
                    android:color="#0000"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dip"
                    android:color="#FF00BB2B" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

Картинку перемещаю вручную в папку **res/drawable-hdpi**
Только есть небольшая проблема, что селектор `android:state_pressed="true"` всё равно отказывается работать

Comment: Пробовали `ImageButton`?

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Всё равно не выходит

Comment: А куда вы выставляете картинку? в `android:background` или `android:src`?

Comment: В случае ImageButton вставляю в src. В общем если использую в качестве src xml код выше, то на кнопке просто маленький круг с границей, остальное серое. Если использую у ImageButton scaleType, то картинка становится как я и говорил - размытая и с будто отключенным "антиалиазингом". При том, что исходник картинки хорошего качества.

Comment: тогда наверно неправильно добавили картинку. Нужно просто скопировать в папку нужной плотнисти, например `drawable-xhdpi`

Comment: Опять же картинка на кнопке в очень низком качестве. Вообще не понимаю в чем дело.

Comment: У тебя точно в  каждой папке drawable лежит картинка нужного разрешения?

Comment: А картинка "плохого качества" - на шаблоне или уже в продукте? В шаблонах специально качество может быть снижено для производительности.

Comment: Прочитайте внимательнее мой ответ, как работает селектор - айтем с `android:state_pressed="true"` должен быть выше дефолтного (без стейта). Сейчас у вас первым выполняется айтем без стейта и поскольку у него нет никаких условий, то совпадение найдено и на этом работа селектора заканчивается

Comment: Поменял, но проблема была не в этом. В обработчике OnTouchListener возвращалось true, а не false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По описанию проблема в том, что нет ресурса с достаточным качеством картинки. Либо ресурс с соответствующим квалификатором отсутствует вовсе (например *res/drawable-xxhdpi/*), либо хранящееся в нем изображение имеет низкое качество - собственный размер в пикселях мал для данного разрешения или достаточный размер, но неудачный скалинг, то есть размер нормальный, но в результате обработки по увеличению получилась хрень вместо четкой картинки.
Так, для экрана плотностью XXHDPI (~480dp) изображение для стандартной иконки (размер 48x48dp) должно иметь абсолютные геометрические размеры 144x144 пикселя с содержимым соответствующего качества (подробнее [смотрите офф.документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=ru#DesigningResources)).

В первом случае недостающие ресурсы нужно создать, во втором посмотреть, что там за изображения вообще лежат и привести их в соответствие.

PS: селектор у вас составлен неверно. В конце селектора должен быть айтем для вида по умолчанию, который не имеет никаких стейтов (в вашем случае вместо `<item android:state_pressed="false">` должен быть просто `<item>` и располагаться самым последним в иерархии айтемов. Выбор айтема в селекторе производится по следующему алгоритму: проверяется условие стейта первого айтема, если совпадает, то он выводится и селектор заканчивает работу, иначе переходит ко второму айтем и проверяет его условие и так далее, если ни одно из условий не выполняется последним выполняется айтем без условий, который содержит, как правило, нормальный вид (состояние без всяких нажатий, фокусов, селекторов и тд).
Картинку в селекторе не видно, потому что ее закрывает `shape` - фигуры не прозрачные по умолчанию. Смотрите, например [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534056/177345) (вторая часть) по созданию вида из наложения картинки и шейпа.

Comment: Ваши советы отчасти помогли. Теперь показывается ректангл и картинка, которая теперь на всю кнопку, но она всё равно низкого качества и с "лесенками". Как по офф документации поправил картинку до 144х144 пиксела и переместил в папку drawable/xxhdpi, в самой android studio по дабл клику показывается в нормальном качестве - а на двух тестируемых устройствах в плохом.

Comment: @ЯктенсТид так же аналогично необходимо создать и папки для других плотностей (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxxhdpi) с изображениями соответствующего размера (смотрите офф.документацию по ссылке в ответе)

Answer (score 2):

Подробная документация от Google расскажет о Button

[ссылка на документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

А так же можно почитать о файлах ресурсов

[ссылка на документацию по поводу ресурсов](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Так же, что бы избежать деформации картинки, советую изучить такую вещь как VectorDrawable, по ссылке выше есть описание.

Answer (score 2):

Знаю, что не всем подойдет совет, но почему бы не использовать ImageView, для которой, как и для кнопки, прикрепить OnClickListener?

Comment: По мне так вполне себе вариант, если не нужно никаких анимаций нажатия и удерживания на элементе.